# Mongoid foreign key in embedded document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Let's say I have two models: board, that belongs to an user, and sharing which is embedded into board

board.rb

```
belongs_to :user
embeds_one :sharing
```

is possible to set the foreign key "user_id" in a field in sharing, something like:

```
belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'sharing.user_id'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just add user_id as a field on your embedded Sharing model.

Comment: And how to reference it as a foreign key? sharing.user_id or sharing[:user_id]

Comment: In general, if its a dynamic field it can't be referenced via the `.` so you have to use the `[]` notation. However for embedded documents you should be all right using the dot notation.

Comment: I'm positive it works, I've done it before. Please read the documentation. http://mongoid.org/docs/documents/dynamic.html

Comment: Tried with sharing.shared_with (shared with is definet not dynamic) and it says it doesn't accept dots... Tried using the array syntax it works